# Adding multiple hyperlinks MSAccess

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

so I am creating a database that contains news reports.

For many rows, I want to be able to add multiple hyperlinks as the content is based on multiple articles online. I came up with making two tables, linking the one row of the first table to multiple rows of the other table by a certain ID (one-for-many relationships).

By creating a report, I can add multiple links but it shows up incorrect if I want to obtain a report that looks as follows:

**Subject**

1. this is the content of the first subtopic - (hyperlink 1, hyperlink 2, etc)
2. this is the content of the second subtopic - (hyperlink 3, hyperlink 4, etc)

How can I achieve this in MS Access?

Comment: Question is about report design, not programming and is therefore not suited to SO. Use report Sorting & Grouping to organize data. If you really want hyperlinks concatenated to a comma separated string, that would require VBA.

Comment: So if you use VBA to do so, would you have to apply a certain code each time you want to add multiple hyperlinks to a row or only once?

Comment: If each hyperlink is in its own record then every time you want to produce comma separated string output, procedure would have to be run. Concatenating data from multiple records is a common topic. Search "ConcatRelated Allen Browne".

Comment: Can you post a picture on how does it look, and how do you want it to be?